# Annotation Processor Spec File Extension

Tags: java

So I've just started working with annotation processors, and read about the 2 ways to register. I prefer the ServiceLoader approach, but I have a question:
What is the "javax.annotation.processing.Processor" file's extension? Is it Processor, or txt, or java, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

After some research and testing, I've found out that "javax.annotation.processing.Processor" is the exact file name, including its extension, which would be considered "Processor"